# "Output" of observeEvent() in R Shiny

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

can someone give me an advice, what can I do, please? I tried to make "changing variable data types based on user choice". It looks like everything works, but  I don't know how to get modified dataset to future work. I paste there code of my server.

Now when I change variable type, I want to work with modified df1. I get "message("it's working");" if I use char variable and change it to factor. And for example if I choose char variable and try to chenge it to numeric i get warning "Warning in observe() : NAs introduced by coercion", what means that code works (in my opinion). But what i have to do if i want work with modified df1(). How to "save" that change?

**EDITED SERVER**

```
 df1 <- reactive({
      req(input$file1)
      df <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath,
                     header = input$header,
                    sep = input$sep,
                     quote = input$quote)
     df
     
   })
   
   
   colnames <- reactive({ names(df1()) })
   
   observeEvent(df1(), {
     
     updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "class_var",
                              label = "Select Columns",
                              choices = colnames(),
                              selected = "") 
     
   })
   
   ## update when selection changes
   
   # storing the selected variable from the variables list table 
   table.sel <- reactive({
     df1()[,which(colnames(df1()) == col.name()[input$class_var,1])]
   })
   
   modified_df1 = eventReactive(input$chg_class,{
     if( input$choose_class == "Numeric"){
       df1 <- as.numeric(df1()[, input$class_var])
     } else if(input$choose_class == "Factor"){ message("it's working");
       df1 <- as.factor(df1()[, input$class_var])
     } else if( input$choose_class == "Character"){
       df1 <- as.character(df1()[, input$class_var])
     } else if( input$choose_class == "Date"){
       df1 <- as.Date(df1()[, input$class_var])
     }
   })
```

Now when I change variable type, I want to work with modified df1. I get "message("it's working");" if I use char variable and change it to factor. And for example if I choose char variable and try to chenge it to numeric i get warning "Warning in observe() : NAs introduced by coercion", what means that code works (in my opinion). But what i have to do if i want work with modified df1(). How to "save" that change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have the correct answer. If you look at the entry for `observeEvent()` in the Shiny [reference documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/observeEvent.html), you will see that there is another function on the same page: `eventReactive()`. They work almost the same way, but `eventReactive()` returns a reactive object. So, to make your code work the way you want it to work, all you need to do is change your

```
observeEvent(input$chg_class, {
  ...
})
```

to

```
modified_df1 <- eventReactive(input$chg_class, {
  ...
})
```